# Trouble understanding hash_extension tool examples for hash length extension attack (C#)

Tags: hash, .net, md5

I am trying to follow the example of how a hash length extension attack works using the article here: https://www.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks

In this, the author has a concrete example running:

```
 $ ./hash_extender --data data --secret 6 --append append --signature 6036708eba0d11f6ef52ad44e8b74d5b --format md5
```

This returns the new signature (6ee582a1669ce442f3719c47430dadee) and a new string:
64617461800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005000000000000000617070656e64

I understand (or at least I think I do) how this is working. However, for the life of me, I can't get the new signature from the new string.

md5(64617...) returns a hash of 56ba10c13a0bdec489e4e35e26788bf4

Okay so, that new string must be a hex string... setting the 'fancy' output settings seems to confirm this because it shows that 64 61 74 61 80 00, etc are the raw values and not the actual readable* text string.

*I say readable, but I know its full of nulls

But every way I try to convert it, I'm not able to get a value where md5(x) = the new signature. What am I missing?

My understanding is that getting a string version of this isn't going to work, because those nulls, which are critical padding, will be lost, so I have to work with either the byte representation or some other encoding. I have tried using the output-format=html flag which produces "data%80%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00P%00%00%00%00%00%00%00append"

And working from there, but still no luck.

I have tried the following

```
string input = "data%80%00%00%00%...00%00%00append";
byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(input));
byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
```

Which produces a different result from

```
byte[] temp = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(html);
byte[] inputBytes = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecodeToBytes(temp, 0, temp.Length);
```

As well as multiple different ways of converting the 6461... hex string directly into a byte array without the URL-encode go-between

guess I should add an example of what I tried there too:

```
string input = "6461746180000...000617070656e64";
byte[] inputBytes = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length / 2)
    .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16))
    .ToArray();

byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);
```

Edit:
Since there is a question of if I am converting properly, I dumped my byte array to a file right before passing it to my MD5() function, then opened it in a hex editor:
[image]

And here is the example I am trying to follow, from the source linked above:
[image]

Comment: How hex is converted to binary has nothing to do with information security. This  is a pure programming question, off-topic here.

Comment: I included the code because I have no better way to explain what I am trying to do. If I had not included it and just said "I can't make the hash match, what am I doing wrong?" would I have gotten a better answer? I don't actually know the hex conversion is where I am screwing up; that's why I'm asking. I'll go post this elsewhere, sure, but the context of the question means I suspect I'm going to get a lot of very generic conversion functions as answers that will leave me no closer to understanding why it doesn't produce the correct hash

Comment: From my understanding the trouble you have is to decode the data from hex or url-encoded to binary - which is not an information security problem. But maybe I'm understanding your question wrong - in which case please show that you've mastered the decoding step (which is not a security topic) and instead focus on the hashing.